# How to remove left and right margin on first and last div

Tags: css

I have more than 100 divs on the page and each row has 3 divs. I want to remove left margin from first div and right margin from right div whereas center div should have 15px margin from left and right. Please guide me how can I do that without giving specific classes (no margin) on each div. Here is the example

[image]
here is my css code

```
.prp_box{
    margin:15px 15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#5f03a6;
    }
```

Comment: Add your html with their respective css.  This is not enough you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/VHXEp/

Use `nth-child(n)` CSS3 selector.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the nth-child css selector.

```
#container:nth-child(3n+0)
{
margin-left: 0;
}
#container:nth-child(3n+3)
{
margin-right: 0;
}
```

This code might need a few adjustments, the 3n is how often, so every 3. The number after the + is where to start

Answer (score 0):

Check the JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kpTdE/

```
.prp_box{

    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#5f03a6;
    float:left;

    }
.sec_box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#5f03a6;
     float:left;
    margin-left:30px;


}
.sec3_box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#5f03a6; 
    margin-left:260px;
}
```